# Access Token coming back undefined

Tags: google-openid

So I asked the following question a few days ago:  [Redirect URI not redirecting correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653847/redirect-uri-not-redirecting-correctly/30673463#30673463)

I've since gotten further along, but now I need my access token to verify a JWT.

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference), googleUser.getAuthResponse().access_token should return the access token, but it's coming back undefined.

I'm a bit confused by all of the different ways that Sign In with Google can be implemented, so if I already have a JWT and the access token is undefined, is that OK?  I'm trying to verify the JWT with the code found [here](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-verifytoken-csharp/blob/master/verifytoken.ashx.cs), but I'm not using an X509 cert.  If figured I should be able to just do it with my client_id and secret.

Can someone please help me get out of this maze? :)